# Deleting buddypress account without deleting user

Tags: buddypress

I've recently started using Buddypress in conjunction with a plugin called memberpress on a site, and am running into a problem:

Basically, if you're logged in to the site, as the Admin for example, and you go to the buddypress profile page link, you're automatically set up with a buddypress membership/profile and listed in the member directory.

I don't want everyone who logs into the site to just automatically/accidentally become a buddypress member and to be listed in the directory.

So I need to A)know how to delete the buddypress membership when that occurs without deleting the user and their ability to log into the site and B)better yet, stop buddypress from automatically assigning membership without purposeful signup.

Any insight would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Buddy press works not connection but using the user table for users profiles. It means if you delete user or buddy press profile both result same delete both.

It might possible

Case 1 hide buddy press profile from public by deregister profile for the user
Case 2 hide user from member directory only.